# How to get a promise in a callback from a react component without state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

is there a way to recive a Promise from a react component, without using state.
The example below shows the problem.
The methode *prepareActivityStop()* should return true, only after the *Workflow Wizard* return `true`.
I cant use any state, and dont know how to do it.

```
 public async prepareActivityStop(pCancelable: boolean): Promise<boolean> {
       

            //Create React Element
            let tElement = (
                <WorkflowWizard
                    shipmentCluster={clusterResult}
                    finish={this.finish}
                ></WorkflowWizard>
            );

            //Render React Element
            ReactDOM.render(tElement, tContainer.element);
        }

      
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add callback to a `WorkflowWizard` i.e. `onDone` and use `Promise` constructor:

```js
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const tElement = (
        <WorkflowWizard
            shipmentCluster={clusterResult}
            finish={this.finish}
            onDone={resolve}
        />
    );

    ReactDOM.render(tElement, tContainer.element);
})
```